# Package Footnote and Biblatex: only fullcites in table

Tags: tables, biblatex, footnotes

I have a question about citation in tables/tabulars.

I use biblatex with style `verbose-ibid` and the package `footnote` to get the cites working in tables/tabulars: Here I use `\savenotes` and `\spewnotes` to retrieve the cites from my table.
The problem is, I obviously don't get the wanted `\autocite` but some other citation-style, always something that would be the `\fullcite` from biblatex.

Look at my MWE: After a shorthand is introduced, it should also be used by `\autocite`! But in my tables I always get a fullcite. Also my text-cite 7 should know the shorthand, which is introduced in the table, but it doesn't.

Any ideas to get the `footnote`-package working with biblatex?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibl.bib}
@BOOK{something,
title={{Fulltitle with many many characters}},
shorthand={SHORTHAND},
address = {City},
publisher = {Publ},
year = {1961},
language = {{Latin}},
}
@BOOK{another,
title={{Another Fulltitle with many many characters}},
shorthand={ANOTHERSHORTHAND},
address = {City},
publisher = {Publ},
year = {1963},
language = {{Latin}},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage[
style=verbose-ibid,
backend=biber,
bibwarn=true,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibl.bib}

\begin{document}


bla\autocite[1]{something}
bla\autocite[2]{something}

%table
\newcommand{\tabcolA}{p{\dimexpr 0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}

\savenotes
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|\tabcolA | \tabcolA | \tabcolA |}
\hline
  header & header & header \\
  \hline
  some text with footnote\autocite[3]{something} & sometext & some text with footnote\autocite[4]{something} \\
  some text with footnote\autocite[5]{another} & sometext & some text with footnote\autocite[6]{another} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Differences in some texts}
  \label{tab:mytextdiff}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
\spewnotes

bla\autocite[7]{another}. bla\autocite[8]{something}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: About the MWE: If someone knows how to get rid of the `filecontents`-warning `LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file ./bibl.bib.` I'm also thankful.

Comment: The `filecontents`-warning is no trouble at all, if you use `filecontents*` the file will be overwritten if present whereas the standard `filecontents` will not do so.

Comment: I'm afraid that `biblatex` tracker facilities are not enabled in floats (tables and the like), so this will probably not work, see §4.11.5 *Trackers in Floats and TOC/LOT/LOF* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure. Footnotes in tables are really a problem in LaTeX (not just for `biblatex`), maybe it's better to avoid them. The problem is that it is quite hard for `biblatex`/LaTeX to know where a float might and up, let alone a footnote spawned in a float, so the tracking really suffers. What you might try though is the `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext` idea in table.

Comment: Thx for your quick answer. Yes, I had the same idea and I'm working on a workaround. Just two things are missing: 1) What biblatex-command do I need to get the proper content for `\footnotetext`? `\footcitetext` puts is content in round brackets, and `\cite` doesn't end with the proper punctuation.

 
2) I also use the `Hyperref`-Package to make my footnotemarks jump to the footnotetext. What would be a proper code to do this manually? (footnotemark and -text)?

Comment: Ad 1) Use `\footcitetext`, but not in a `\footnotetext` as `\footcitetext` wraps its argument in  `\footnotetext` automatically. Ad 2) I'm not sure, does the the combination of `\footnotemark` and `\footcitetext`  not link correctly? (It seemed to work in a short test document of mine.) So you would write `\footnotemark\footcitetext{wilde}`.

Comment: Note though that the trackers will behave as though you cited the work in order of the `\footcitetext` calls, you will have to do a lot of things (and checking) manually.

Comment: Ok, `\footcitetext` works fine. Counters (if it's just the footnote-counter) - no problem. But yes, the `\footnotemark` doesn't link to the footnote correctly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to moewe and this nice codesnippet [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2846), I could put together a working code: With a bit manual work (see code below) now footnotes in tables should act like `biblatex`-footnotes and work together with the `hyperref`-package. (The `footnote`-package couldn't help.)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibl.bib}
@BOOK{something,
title={{Fulltitle with many many characters}},
shorthand={SHORTHAND},
address = {City},
publisher = {Publ},
year = {1961},
language = {{Latin}},
}
@BOOK{another,
title={{Another Fulltitle with many many characters}},
shorthand={ANOTHERSHORTHAND},
address = {City},
publisher = {Publ},
year = {1963},
language = {{Latin}},
}
\end{filecontents*}


%   HEADER
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage[
style=verbose-ibid,
backend=biber,
bibwarn=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{bibl.bib}

\usepackage{alphalph}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Footnotemark}{%
    \footnotemark%
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname saved@Href@\alphalph{\value{footnote}}\endcsname%
    \Hy@footnote@currentHref%
}

\newcommand{\BeforeFootnotetext}{%
    \stepcounter{footnote}%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\Hy@footnote@currentHref\csname saved@Href@\alphalph{\value{footnote}}\endcsname%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

autocite-footnote, introducing shorthand\autocite[1]{something}\\
autocite-footnote, using shorthand\autocite[2]{something}


\newcounter{fncounter}\setcounter{fncounter}{\value{footnote}}%save the fn-counter

%table
\newcommand{\tabcolA}{p{\dimexpr 0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|\tabcolA | \tabcolA | \tabcolA |}
\hline
  header & header & header \\
  \hline
  use shorthand in table\Footnotemark & sometext & somtext \\
  a note, note a cite\Footnotemark & sometext & introduce a shorthand in table\Footnotemark \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Differences in some texts}
  \label{tab:mytextdiff}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier


\setcounter{footnote}{\value{fncounter}}%restore the fncounter and add the foonotetexts:


\BeforeFootnotetext%do this before each \footcitetext or \footnote-statment
\footcitetext[3]{something}%3 is the PAGEnumber!

\BeforeFootnotetext
\mkbibfootnotetext{A note without punctation? Will be added by biblatex}

\BeforeFootnotetext
\footcitetext[5]{another}%6 is the PAGEnumber!

\clearpage

autocite, using shorthand\autocite[6]{something}.\\
autocite, using shorthand introduced in table\autocite[7]{another}.


\printbibliography
\printshorthands


\end{document}
```

Comment: I would not go about like this. Write `some text with footnote\footnotemark` in the table and add the `\footcitetext[3]{something}` after the table in the right order.

Comment: I think you've meant the `\autocite` inside the tables. This was just for testing. Check my new try, it seems to work fine. And thanks again!

Comment: Hmmm, in my tests, I did not need any of the new `\Footnotemark` or `\BeforeFootnotetext` commands even for proper linking. But if it works for you, it works for you.