# Footnote citations (\notefullcite) not appearing when called from tabular

Tags: tables, biblatex, footnotes

So I have a pretty heavy custom setup for a grant application, where I need my citations to appear as footnotes.  I've got this set up fine, but I have a problem when I try to cite something from a tabular environment.  Namely, the citation shows up properly in the table, but the reference does not appear in the footnotes.  Those numbers just go missing...

I've put up a minimum working example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@article{ref1,
Author = {SoAndSo, One},
Title = {Somearticle 1},
Year = {1993},
}
@article{ref2,
Author = {SoAndSo, Two},
Title = {Somearticle 2},
Year = {1994},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, firstinits=true, maxnames=99,bibstyle=numeric-comp, citestyle=custom-numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mytestbib.bib}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]}

\begin{document}
\noindent Paper: \notefullcite{ref1}\\
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  Paper: & \notefullcite{ref2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

When I compile, I get only the first reference appearing in the footnotes... Any ideas? I can see from the related questions that footnotes from tabulars are a mess... I'm definitely seeing some trouble getting the workarounds to respect all my bibtex stuff too...

[EDIT REVISED:] The \notefullcite command is defined as follows:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\notefullcite}[\mkbibbrackets]% 
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{notefullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{notefullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
       \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}.}}}
```

Comment: Welcome! As posted, your MWE cannot be compiled without error. Does the problem go away if you use a standard Biblatex style? If so, can you use a standard one in your MWE? If not, and the problem is specific to your custom style, you'll need to post the style in order for us to help. I tried replacing it with `numeric-comp`, but then your citation commands are undefined control sequences.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, I was afraid of that! It is specific to the style I think, because it has to do with the footnote citations.  I have updated with a link to the style file.

Comment: Will you have a `table` around the `tabular`? If not the solution at [Footnote in tabular environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109471/35864) will work just fine. If you do have a `table` environment, the solution won't work and we will all sorts of additional troubles since the cite trackers you need to decide whether or not to print the full citation are switched off inside floats, see §4.11.5 *Trackers in Floats and TOC/LOT/LOF*, p. 239 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: See also [\footcite always prints long citation if used in `figure` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252723/35864) for the float issue.

Comment: You can use the `savenotes` environment of the `footnote` package together with the hack in the answer above to get things right.

Comment: @moewe I am not using a table at the moment.  Thanks for the tips! I'd like to have something that works in general, but I will probably wait to test this out until after I submit my proposal tonight...

Comment: I would argue that if you use a `table`, you should not expect the cite tracker to work since text and floats are in a way independent. But since you use only `tabular` I think `\usepackage{footnote}makesavenoteenv{tabular}` should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution which you may be able to adapt to the custom style you are using. It is based on `numeric-comp` which I assume is similar. It defines a new command `\footfullcitetext` which is a cross between `\footfullcite` and `\footcitetext`. The usual trick is required to typeset the footnote i.e. placing it outside the `tabular` environment.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
  @article{ref1,
    Author = {SoAndSo, One},
    Title = {Somearticle 1},
    Year = {1993},
  }
  @article{ref2,
    Author = {SoAndSo, Two},
    Title = {Somearticle 2},
    Year = {1994},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, firstinits=true, maxnames=99,bibstyle=numeric-comp, citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mytestbib.bib}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\noindent Paper: \footfullcite{ref1}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{cc}
  Paper: & \footnotemark
\end{tabular}
\footfullcitetext{ref2}
\end{document}
```

[image: footnote citations including one from tabular]

Comment: Hmm, for my custom-numeric-comp it breaks the numbering and the sizes are a little off.  But the principal is good, I'll try to tweak it a bit.  Thanks for the help, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I can't quite figure out how to make this idea work with the custom style as I'm not sure what to use in place of `\mkbibfootnotetext`, but perhaps somebody else will be able to build on this to provide an answer closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, I found a super hacky workaround.  What I did was define a new macro \hidefullcite which makes an invisible citation; the reference will appear as a footnote, but nothing appears in the text.  Then I can cite everything before the table.  Within the table, references appear correct because they are referring to something that has already been cited.  For example,

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\hidefullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}
   \usebibmacro{notefullcite}}
  {}
  {}

\newbibmacro*{notefullcite}{
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{
       \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}.}}}
```

Then I just call

```
\noindent Paper: \notefullcite{ref1}\\
\hidefullcite{ref2}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  Paper: & \notefullcite{ref2}
\end{tabular}
```

and everything is peachy.  Thanks to cfr for the help, your fix didn't work for my custom mess, but it gave me the motivation to poke around a bit. (I'd still be interested in seeing a nicer fix, if anyone knows how to modify cfr's fix or something similar to the custom citation format.)