# APA-Style: Et al. does not appear (any more) in figure's captions

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib, apa-style

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,oneside,headsepline]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber,uniquename=false,pagetracker=true]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

    \DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1} 
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
        andothers = {{et al\adddot}},  } 


    \usepackage{filecontents}   
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{zapkau2015,
      author   = {Florian B. Zapkau and Christian Schwens and Holger Steinmetz and R{\"u}diger Kabst},
      title    = {Disentangling the effect of prior entrepreneurial exposure on entrepreneurial intention},
      journal  = {Journal of Business Research},
      year     = {2015},
      volume   = {68},
      number   = {3},
      pages    = {639 - 653},
      issn     = {0148-2963},
      keywords = {Prior entrepreneurial exposure, Role models, Work experience, Entrepreneurial intention, Theory of planned behavior },
    }
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{document}    

    Some Text ...\citep{zapkau2015}.
    More Text ... 

    \begin{figure}[h]
      \centering
      \caption{Caption Text \citet{zapkau2015}.} \label{fig:forschungsmodell}
      \vspace{2ex}
      \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{TPB.eps}\\
    \end{figure}


    \end{document}
```

Here my problem is: 
Citing zapkau for the first time brings the all author's names. And here, that is right. Citing zapkau more than one time brings an "et al." after the author's names when being used in the text.

[image]

[image: Citing for the second time.]

PROBLEM:

When citing in a figure's caption, it's again:

[image: Too many authors even though there has to be et al.]

I scanned other solutions but there does not seem to be one which works in my case. Thanks in advance for your help! :-)

Comment: Please add a minimal working example http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that . +Add the bib entries. +image could be: ` \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} `.

Comment: `epsfig` is a package existing only for back compatibility with older documents and should not be used in new documents. Use `graphicx` and `\includegraphics`. It's not the cause for the problem. The example is far from minimal.

Comment: Please provide the `zapkau2015` bib entry.

Comment: This is by design. `biblatex` considers figures to be outside the flow of text. So its 'trackers' are disabled there. So `biblatex` can not check if an entry has been seen/cited before in a figure. Have a look at [\footcite always prints long citation if used in `figure` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252723/35864). If that does not work for you, please prepare a proper [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/358640)/[MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864): most of the packages in your preamble are not important to the question, yet we lack the bib file.

Comment: I have edited your question a bit. We do not have your `.eps` and there was the classic `\DeclareLanguageMapping` missing.

Comment: BTW: My linked solution works for me. Did it for you? If not, why/how not?

Comment: Sorry, I was just editing it either. I addressed both issues. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: It does work, yes. Problem would be if there appears a first mention in the caption. I guess there is no beautiful solution so this one should be close enough.

Comment: What do you want to happen in this case? Do you just want the short citation regardless and the first in-text citation long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `biblatex` disables citation tracking within figures as explained in [\footcite always prints long citation if used in `figure` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252723/35864), you could re-enable citation tracking in figures as described in the answer there.
That is probably the 'best' solution if you consider float objects to form part of the text and want things to behave as if they appeared in text.

Alternatively, you can just reset the non-tracking behaviour of `\ifciteseen` in floats

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \apptocmd\@floatboxreset
    {\let\blx@imc@ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}
    {}
    {\blx@err@patch{floats}}%
}
\makeatother
```

This will cause all citations in floats to appear in the shortened version and not the long first-cite version.

---

Since you are using the `natbib` compatibility mode that defines starred command versions, we might as well redefine those. *Normally*, the starred version of a cite command in `natbib` compatibility mode would print all authors. The code for that, however, does not work for `biblatex-apa`. So the starred `natbib`-commands are useless with `biblatex-apa`.
We can revive them and make them do the opposite: Always print out the shortened list, no matter what anything else says.

```
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\citet}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\let\ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}}%
     \textcite}
    {\textcite}}
\makeatletter
```

Should be enough.

Mico's MWE then gives

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zapkau2015,
  author   = {Florian B. Zapkau and Christian Schwens 
     and Holger Steinmetz and R{\"u}diger Kabst},
  title    = {Disentangling the effect of prior 
     entrepreneurial exposure on entrepreneurial 
     intention},
  journal  = {Journal of Business Research},
  year     = {2015},
  volume   = {68},
  number   = {3},
  pages    = {639 - 653},
  issn     = {0148-2963},
  keywords = {Prior entrepreneurial exposure, Role 
     models, Work experience, Entrepreneurial intention, 
     Theory of planned behavior},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber,
    uniquename=false,pagetracker=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}    % <-- optional

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\citet}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\let\ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}}%
     \textcite}
    {\textcite}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}    
Some Text \dots\ \citep{zapkau2015}.

More Text \dots\ \citep{zapkau2015}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption Text \dots\ \citet*{zapkau2015}.} % <-- new 
  \label{fig:forschungsmodell}
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{TPB.eps}
\end{figure}

More Text \dots\ \citep{zapkau2015}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be the most elegant solution. Is there any reason for the behaviour biblatex shows? I mean, why should the citation always be printed in the long version when appearing in captions and other float objects?

Comment: @junkmaster Well, as I said there are good reasons to disable the tracking mechanisms in floats, since they are outside the flow of text. (See also my linked answer.) I don't think there is a good reason that citations in floats now always appear in their long form, it is simply a consequence of the code structure. (If tracking is disabled, `\ifciteseen` always yields false, making `biblatex-apa` believe all citations are first citations that require the long form.)

Answer (score 2):

If the `biblatex` package is loaded with the option `natbib=true`, it provides emulation of some of the "core" commands of the `natbib` citation management package -- but not for all of `natbib`'s macros and options, such as the option `longnamesfirst`, which directs `\citet` and `\citep` to typeset the full list of authors the very first time an entry is cited and an abbreviated list ("et al") for subsequent citation call-outs.

However, natbib's commands `\defcitealias` and `\citetalias` *are* emulated if the option `natbib=true` is set. I therefore suggest you make use of them to create abbreviated-list citation call-outs inside `\caption` commands. It's admittedly a little bit kludgy, but I trust your document doesn't have all that many instances of creating citation call-outs inside `\caption` directives...

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zapkau2015,
  author   = {Florian B. Zapkau and Christian Schwens 
     and Holger Steinmetz and R{\"u}diger Kabst},
  title    = {Disentangling the effect of prior 
     entrepreneurial exposure on entrepreneurial 
     intention},
  journal  = {Journal of Business Research},
  year     = {2015},
  volume   = {68},
  number   = {3},
  pages    = {639 - 653},
  issn     = {0148-2963},
  keywords = {Prior entrepreneurial exposure, Role 
     models, Work experience, Entrepreneurial intention, 
     Theory of planned behavior},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber,
    uniquename=false,pagetracker=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defcitealias{zapkau2015}{Zapkau et~al.\ (2015)} % <-- new
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}    % <-- optional

\begin{document}    
Some Text \dots\ \citep{zapkau2015}.

More Text \dots\ \citep{zapkau2015}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption Text \dots\ \citetalias{zapkau2015}.} % <-- new 
  \label{fig:forschungsmodell}
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{TPB.eps}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: While this certainly works it seems to go against the spirit of `bibilatex` to have to define a cite alias with information that `biblatex` could provide automatically. If I were to define a new cite command I would just make one that always has `\ifciteseen` true.

Comment: @moewe - I did write that the approach taken in this answer is "a little bit kludgy". :-) I think it would be very useful if you provided a separate answer that goes with the spirit of `biblatex` and, in particular, shows how to set up a custom citation command that always sets `\ifciteseen` to true. I guess such a custom citation command would emulate the behavior of `natbib`'s `\citep*` and `\citet*` directives, right? Or, feel free to edit my answer. :-)

Comment: I have added an answer that reverses the behaviour of the starred commands from the `natbib` compatibility mode.

Comment: I meant 'reverses'. According to http://merkel.texture.rocks/Latex/natbib.php as well as the code in `blx-natbib.def`, the starred versions give the full list of names, while the unstarred might truncate the list. My new starred command always truncates, hence 'reversing' (but certainly not reproducing) the default behaviour.

Comment: @moewe - Thanks! You're correct, natbib's "starred" citation commands provide the full list of authors, not the truncated list. Glad you caught this!

Comment: Maybe you can edit your answer a bit to clarify what `\citet*` and `\citep*` actually do. In fact `biblatex`'s `natbib` compatibility mode copies the exact behaviour of `natbib`'s commands for the standard styles and most custom styles, but the way this is set up does not work with `biblatex-apa` specifically.

Comment: @moewe - I've taken you up on your suggestion. :-)

Comment: Thank you. The point here is however not that `longnamesfirst` is not supported, the point is that `biblatex`'s citation tracker is turned off in floats. So that bit is still somewhat misleading, I think, especially since `biblatex-apa` basically implements the APA's version of `longnamesfirst`.