# ext-biblatex print full author + [shorthand] on first cite with ext-authoryear-ibid

Tags: biblatex, ibidem

I am using the style ext-authoryear-ibid.
I am trying to achieve an output like this (shorthand in "[]" if exists):

1. First cite: (National Aeronautics and Space Administration
   [NASA], 2022, p. 12)
2. Second cite: (ibid., p. 14)
3. Another source: (Doe, John, 2019, p. 550)
4. n-th cite: (NASA, 2022, p. 102)

Meaning, that only for the first cite, if a shorthand exists, use (1). For all subsequent cites use the shorthand only, but only if there was something cited in between. Otherwise use ibid.

I am currently some code which almost does what I want. The problem is, that it disables the ibid function. MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    paper=A4,
    fontsize=12pt,
]{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    sorting=nyt,
    style=ext-authoryear-ibid,
    citecounter,
    citetracker=true,
]{biblatex}

% Comma between title and year
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\adddot\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

% Hack for shortauthor, disables ibidem
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
        {\ifboolexpr{
                test{\ifnameundef{shortauthor}}
                or
                test{\ifciteseen}
            }
            {\printnames{labelname}%
                \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}
            {\printnames[labelname]{author}%
                \ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{1}
                {\setunit{\addspace}%
                    \printtext[parens]{\printnames{labelname}}}%
                {}%
                \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{testbib.bib}
    @online{test1,
        author = {{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}},
        shortauthor = {NASA},
        title = {Aliens},
        year = {2022}
    }
    
    @online{test2,
        author = {John Doe},
        title = {Generic Names},
        year = {2019}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\begin{document}
    \parencite[][12]{test1}\par \parencite[][14]{test1} $\rightarrow$ needs to be: (ibid., 2022, p. 14)\par \parencite[][550]{test2}\par \parencite[][102]{test1}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redefinition of the `cite` bibmacro shown in the question appears to be based on the definition from [`authoryear.cbx` (ll. 10-18 in v3.17)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/64156e27b9501bab86cab5ed9ee58e8a6a5ce67f/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear.cbx#L10-L18). For your style (`ext-authoryear-ibid`) the redefinition should be based on the `cite` bibmacro from [`authoryear-ibid.cbx` (ll. 18-29)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/64156e27b9501bab86cab5ed9ee58e8a6a5ce67f/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear-ibid.cbx#L18-L29).

If we change the approach slightly to be more flexible and allow for `shorteditor` (and indeed for all kinds of `short...` name fields if you should want to define additional ones) we might end up with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-ibid,
  citetracker,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\adddot\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

% some auxiliary macros to
% check if we are in the shortauthor/shorteditor case
% and to strip the "short" from those field names to get the "long" field
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ifstartswithshort}[1]{\ifstartswithshort@i #1short\stopscanning}
\newcommand*{\ifstartswithshort@i}{}
\def\ifstartswithshort@i#1short#2\stopscanning{\ifblank{#1}}

\newcommand*{\iffieldstartswithshort}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifstartswithshort
  \expandafter{\expanded{\thefield{#1}}}}

\newcommand*{\stripshort}[1]{\stripshort@i #1\stopscanning}
\newcommand*{\stripshort@i}{}
\def\stripshort@i#1short#2\stopscanning{#2}

\newcommand*{\stripshortfromfield}[1]{%
  \expandafter\stripshort
  \expandafter{\expanded{\thefield{#1}}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
          {\ifciteseen
             {\printnames{labelname}}
             {\iffieldstartswithshort{labelnamesource}
                {\printnames[labelname]{\stripshortfromfield{labelnamesource}}%
                 \setunit{\addspace}%
                 \printtext[parens]{\printnames{labelname}}}
                {\printnames{labelname}}}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{test1,
  author      = {{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}},
  shortauthor = {NASA},
  title       = {Aliens},
  year        = {2022},
}
@online{test2,
  author = {John Doe},
  title  = {Generic Names},
  year   = {2019}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \parencite[][12]{test1}

  \parencite[][14]{test1}
  
  \parencite[][550]{test2}
  
  \parencite[][102]{test1}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (National Aeronautics and Space Administration [NASA], 2022, p. 12) (ibid., p. 14) (Doe, 2019, p. 550) (NASA, 2022, p. 102)]

Note that we didn't use `citecounter`, we used the simpler `\ifciteseen` test.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to solve it. The only problem I see is that using ```\caption{\parencite{}}``` (inside a figure) will introduce the first long name including ```shorthand```  in brackets each time. I am afraid, that this can not be easily tackled by biblatex macros. But I would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: @PeterByron Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356231/35864.